# Set different margins for even and odd pages

Tags: margins, double-sided

I have a class file for my document where I have declared margins:

```
\setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}%
```

with the left one bigger. But I wanted odd pages to have a bigger left margin and even pages to have a bigger right margin. So I tried:

```
\checkoddpage 
  \ifoddpage
    \setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}%
  \else 
    \setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{3.5cm}{*}%
  \fi
```

but it seems that it always returns true in a if statement. 
How can I do it?

Comment: all the standatrd classes have a built in `[twoside]` option and then separate settings `\@oddsidemargin` and `\@evensidemargin`You don't say what class you are using and I don't recognise the commands but it will have the same feature as the odd/even margin support is built into the core latex format. Traditionally odd pages have smaller left margin than even pages.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Your comments are an answer.

Comment: @egreg : Thanks for your encouragement. Ecco!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks as if you might be using the `memoir` document class, so here's an answer for that case.

`\setlrmarginsandblock` actually sets the margins as they would be on a recto or odd-numbered page in a document intended for two-sided printing. Thus left corresponds to the inner margin and right to the outer.

If you use the `oneside` class option, all pages will be laid out the same.

If you use the `twoside` option, then the recto pages will be laid out as you specify, and the verso (even) pages will be laid out with the margins reversed.

You should use `\setlrmarginsandblock` just once, in the preamble (before `\begin{document}`). Don't forget that you will also need to call `\checkandfixthelayout` to put your layout into effect.

Comment: You are right, using `twoside` was all I needed, so simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can `\usepackage[inner=1cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}` and set  those options to whatever you like.

Comment: Is the syntax correct?